# How to check status and cancel an asynchronous task?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, asynchronous

Currently, I am working on a rest API through which client can submit a forever running task and it should return started confirmation if there is no error. The client should be able to submit any number of similar tasks. There should be a functionality to check the status and cancel any task. Currently, I am trying to do it in Java using Spring. How should I approach the problem?

I was able to create an asynchronous task in Spring each time I sent a post request. But till now unable to figure out how to check the status and cancel any task.

Comment: By generating a unique identifier for each task and storing them in some collection or Map. When you want to cancel a task, submit its identifier, find it thanks to this identifier in the collection or Map, cancel it (and remove it from the collection).

Comment: Your question is very broad. I see at least the following distinct questions hiding in it:
1. How to run an async task with Spring.
2. How to cancel a task with Spring.
3. How to report progress from a not terminating task with Spring.
If communicating through the necessary information through a web interface is a problem this could be another question.

I recommend creating separate questions for each of those.
Please also show that you tried to solve the problem yourself and what the results of those attempts were.

This will increase you chance of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Threads you can use here.
Create a job executor class responsible for running the task.
Make a callable. So, you would be able to get the result in the Future.

Use BlockingQueue for the task to store and pick from it (you should because of processor i.e. dual/4 cores).

Use Runtime Class to get the Cores available and Run the thread in cores-1.
No. of thread = Available cores-1.

for cancellation, you can use a flag that mapped to respected stored Thread. Check that flag and return if thread started at any point of time